# jquery html5 local storage - radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, local-storage

I got this code from http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/jquery-plugin-for-caching-forms-using-html5-local-storage/. It works for text input, checkboxes, and options selection but not radio buttons unfortunately. I want to be able to store what user selected previously for the radio buttons during page reload or when user accidentally closed the webpage.. Below is the code. Please help!

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>HTML5 and CSS3 Validation</title>
 <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page">
    <section id="signup">
        <header>Sign up to the website!</header>

        <form name="signup-form">
            <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" title="Please enter your firstname" placeholder="Jonny" autofocus required />

            <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" title="Please enter your surname" placeholder="Schnittger" required />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" title="Please enter your email address" placeholder="jonny@schnittger.me" required />

            <label for="website">Website:</label>
            <input id="website" name="website" type="url" title="Please enter the url to your website (optional)" placeholder="http://schnittger.me" />

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" title="Please enter a password, it must contain at least 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase character and be at least 6 characters in length" pattern="^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$" placeholder="******" required />

            <label for="checkbox">Is this checked?:</label>
                            <input id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked />
                            <input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked />

                           <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                            <input name="gender" type="radio" checked="checked">Male
                            <input name="gender" type="radio"  />Female



            <label for="checkbox">Is this checked?:</label>
            <select id="options" name="options">
                <option value="opt-1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="opt-2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="opt-3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="opt-4">Option 4</option>
            </select>

                            <label for="checkbox">Is this checked?:</label>
            <select id="gen" name="gend">
                <option value="opt-1">Male</option>
                <option value="opt-2">Female</option>

            </select>



        </form>
    </section>
     </div>   
 <script>

      (function ( $ ) {
$.fn.FormCache = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
    }, options );

      function on_change(event) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        var key = input.parents('form:first').attr('name');
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);

        if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            data[input.attr('name')] = input.is(':checked');
        }else {
            data[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
        }

        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

        return this.each(function() {    
        var element = $(this);

        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
            var key = element.attr('name');

            var data = false;
            if(localStorage[key]) {
                data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
            }

            if(!data) {
                localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify({});
                data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
            }
            element.find('input, select').change(on_change);

            element.find('input, select').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('type') != 'submit') {
                    var input = $(this);
                    var value = data[input.attr('name')];
                    if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                        if(value) {
                            input.attr('checked', input.is(':checked'));
                        } else {
                            input.removeAttr('checked');
                        }
                    } else {
                        input.val(value);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        else {
            alert('local storage is not available');
          }
       });


   };     
  }( jQuery ));
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').FormCache();


});



</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i don't see any code...?

Comment: I have added the code. The script I got it from the link I have posted in the question. The script (local storage) works fine for input texts, check boxes, option lists, except radio buttons. I am working on my project and most of my survey questions are radio buttons which I desperately need to get it work for radio buttons. Hope someone could help..

Comment: the form is just a trial... not my real form which I just want to test the local storage for all kind of questions in my survey...